# Assembly mismatch when running the exe from a shared folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly

When I start my exe from c:, there is no problem. But when I copy the exe and the DLLs in debug folder to a network share, I get this error when I launch it:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
> or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
> match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: SO didn't let me mark it when I added the question and the answer, now it did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by copying the .exe.config file to the share.